# SQL Server on Linux password complexity policy

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, ubuntu-16.04

From what I can make out from Google, SQL Server on Windows uses the system password complexity policy.

I'm creating users on an SQL Server for Linux instance which is not tied to a domain, using `CREATE LOGIN [...] WITH PASSWORD...`.  Where is the password complexity policy set for this type of user and how can I change it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there even a password policy? For instance can you set a  password of a single character?

Comment: I have SQL server running on Ubuntu 16.04.  When I create a login with a password and the `must change on first use` option and the user tries to login from Windows, a password complexity policy is applied (at least 8 characters, mix of upper, lower and symbols).  I suppose it might be applying the _client's_ Windows complexity policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-security-overview?view=sql-server-ver16

SQL Server on Linux currently has the following limitations:

- A **standard password policy** is provided. MUST_CHANGE is the only option you may configure. CHECK_POLICY option is not supported.

**Standard Complexity** is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-ver16#password-complexity

**Standard (hard coded) expiration 90** days see this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/9147 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1079552/mssql-2019-on-linux-login-expiry-default)

Comment: Haha this is so long ago I can't even remember what project I was using MSSQL on.  Thanks though.